# bluecov bluetooth connect map profile

Tags: dictionary, bluetooth, bluecove

I am trying to connect to map profile using bluecov

```
ClientSession clientSession=null;
clientSession=(ClientSession)Connector.open(serverURL);
hdr=clientSession.createHeaderSet();
hdr.setHeader(HeaderSet.TARGET,"");
hdr=clientSession.connect(hdr);
```

But it does not connect. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you receiving an error, or is it just silently refusing to connect?

Comment: I have found HeaderSet.Target value and connected successfully but sms are not sent . No any response in mobile device. But I when look the logs of bluetooth, content is there.